# Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: maven, gwt, polymer, pom.xml, command-prompt

I'm new to GWT and Maven and I was creating a new **Maven** project and then customizing it using the steps mentioned in this link: [Setting and Customizing your Project](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/polymer-tutorial/create.html).

I followed all the steps given in the Customizing your Project section on that page but while running the project in the SuperDevMode, I got many errors in Command Prompt and I don't understand how to resolve those errors even after searching on the Internet.

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.gwtproject.tutorial</groupId>
  <artifactId>TodoList</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>org.gwtproject.tutorial.TodoList</name>

  <properties>

    <!-- Setting maven.compiler.source to something different to 1.8
         needs that you configure the sourceLevel in gwt-maven-plugin since
         GWT compiler 2.8 requires 1.8 (see gwt-maven-plugin block below) -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <!-- Don't let your Mac use a crazy non-standard encoding -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- ensure all GWT deps use the same version (unless overridden) -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.vaadin.polymer</groupId>
         <artifactId>vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements</artifactId>
         <version>1.7.0.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- Output classes directly into the webapp, so that IDEs and "mvn process-classes" update them in DevMode -->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>

      <!-- GWT Maven Plugin-->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-rc-6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>import-sources</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>import-test-sources</goal>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <moduleName>org.gwtproject.tutorial.TodoList</moduleName>
          <moduleShortName>TodoList</moduleShortName>
          <failOnError>true</failOnError>
          <jsInteropMode>JS</jsInteropMode>
          <!-- GWT compiler 2.8 requires 1.8, hence define sourceLevel here if you use
               a different source language for java compilation -->
          <sourceLevel>1.8</sourceLevel>
          <!-- Compiler configuration -->
          <compilerArgs>
            <!-- Ask GWT to create the Story of Your Compile (SOYC) (gwt:compile) -->
            <arg>-compileReport</arg>
            <arg>-XcompilerMetrics</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
          <!-- DevMode configuration -->
          <warDir>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</warDir>
          <classpathScope>compile+runtime</classpathScope>
          <!-- URL(s) that should be opened by DevMode (gwt:devmode). -->
          <startupUrls>
            <startupUrl>TodoList.html</startupUrl>
          </startupUrls>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Skip normal test execution, we use gwt:test instead -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here's what I got in Command Prompt.

```
C:\Users\TEST>cd TodoListApp
C:\Users\TEST\TodoListApp>mvn war:exploded
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt-maven-plugin/1.0-rc-6/gwt-maven-plugin-1.0-rc-6.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:1.0-rc-6 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt-maven-plugin/1.0-rc-6/gwt-maven-plugin-1.0-rc-6.jar
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-6: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:1.0-rc-6 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building org.gwtproject.tutorial.TodoList 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:1.0-rc-6 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-6: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:1.0-rc-6 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:exploded (default-cli) @ TodoList ---
[INFO] Exploding webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [TodoList] in [C:\Users\TEST\TodoListApp\target\TodoList-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\TEST\TodoListApp\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [66 msecs]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.198 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-29T14:24:43+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/133M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\TEST\TodoListApp>mvn gwt:devmode
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:1.0-rc-6 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-6: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:1.0-rc-6 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:1.0-rc-6 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.316 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-29T14:24:53+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/106M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:1.0-rc-6 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I edited the groupId of GWT Maven Plugin as "org.codehaus.mojo" by seeing the one written in that GWT page and I don't remember now what was the groupId initially. Please help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

The version of your plugin is wrong; Please replace it with `2.8.1`. Like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well, instead of that, I tried replacing the groupId as "net.ltgt.gwt.maven" which was written in the pom.xml file by default. I found that groupId by creating a new project and then observing its pom.xml file and it fixed my issue.

Comment: There are two plugins with two different groupIds (but I think they share the same artifactId). Your solution is probably fine as well (I haven't used yours yet).